# "hold a police sting"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, collocations

> Did they ever hold a police sting in this establishment?

I am not sure if I am correct, but "hold" doesn't seem to be the correct word or the most appropriate word to use. It seems passable, but I think there's a more commonly used word in this context.

Comment: Police *conduct* a sting.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a perfectly valid use of the word "hold" and is quite common. One of the definitions of *to hold* is:

> to engage in; preside over; carry on.

Examples include, "hold a meeting", "hold a lunch", "hold a press conference". All of these imply that whoever is doing the "holding" is orchestrating it or arranging for the particular thing to happen.

In your question, "Did they ever hold a police sting in this establishment?", what is being asked is if "they" (the police) ever orchestrated or arranged for a police sting to happen in the establishment.

An alternative word for *hold* might be *conduct* ("did they ever conduct a police sting in this establishment?"). I don't consider that to be something someone would say casually (maybe an attorney in a court would phrase a question that way, since it sounds more formal), but it is correct.